# 404 of wp-admin pages

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error

I've got a website thats having problems (its been untouched for a few months so not any changes that were made to break it)

when logging in the login page is unstyled, sitting in the top left corner.  I can login ok, but when I try to access dashboard or any /wp-admin/... pages I get a 404. (site loads fine for public content)

I've searched and tried everything I can.

disabled all plugins,
default theme
new .htaccess
phpmyadmin to rename site address

Has anyone experienced this before and have any more ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using any plugins for your login page? Some plugins have an option to display an error page if a anyone tries to access https://site-name/wp-admin and might have changed the link for dashboard. Since you've tried disabling every plugin we can null that out for the time being, i guess. Do you have FTP access to your website? If so did you check if a folder named wp-admin exists?

Comment: When you say 404, are these broken URLs? Correct URLs that just don't work? What happens when you visit them directly? Have you confirmed the files exist in the file system? What happens if you take a fresh copy over WP and drop it over the top? Does the problem go away if you disable all plugins and use a default theme?

Comment: Hi there, Yes all plugins were disabled and same problem. Just checked and wp-admin folder exists and looks like everything is there.

Comment: Do you have access to yourdomain.com/wp-login.php ? 

If so try logging in and accessing the dashboard. If thats working try changing your permalinks once. 

Hope that helps.

Comment: No access to wp-login :( still shows a 404.

Comment: files are definitely there, I replaced with fresh WP, deleted all plugins and left to default theme and still no luck.  However I did get a different error when I tried this which may be useful. "Too many redirects occurring trying to open "www..../wp-admin/". This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to a page which is then redirected to the original page.

Comment: Any other ideas? still not having any luck with this :(

Comment: Is this https or http? And are you sure it's PHP doing the redirecting? Try loading a non-PHP file and see what the results are. Also have you attempted to do a https redirect, or changed the protocol or URL used?

Comment: I can view image files ok (e.g. in wp-uploads) tried changing site url to www and no www versions with no luck. (no SSL setup)

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem. There was an unexpected .htaccess file in wp-admin folder with deny from all! not sure how that got there...

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as correct so it doesn't show as unsolved.